# Issue with loading another page while loading current page in php

Tags: php, email, session

I am having trouble with loading two pages at the same time in one browser. I have file which send emails of 10k. but at the same time I want to browser in the system. However, I cannot do anything until, the script which sends email will finish.

Any advice. how can solve this issue? Please do let me know if you need some more info.

Comment: What do you mean "load two pages"? are you including one file into another?

Comment: no, I mean to load into different windows of browser

Comment: Got it thanks. Did you try Sabeen's answer?

Answer (score 0):

The session locks out new requests. So until the session is closed, the other request waits. Look into [session_write_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

Or you can run another instance in a different browser.

Comment: @akrambek unless your web server is limit to one request at a time, I think this is more likely. Maybe show us some of your code?

Comment: It is actually quite huge I mean my script. Can you advice me how can disable this limit of one request at a time.

Comment: I dont think it would be a web server thing but just to be sure google your relevant web server and see how to figure out the limits on it. Generally the session close would be close to the top of the code, pretty close to session start BEFORE going into your main loop.